# Rxjs : how it's done and async/await

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, rollupjs

I have Observables, Subjects and ect thanks to rxjs,

good, I don't need async/await : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

My question is how do the guys who made rxjs do what they do?

did they use the async function to create their library or did they find a much more optimal solution?

If they did use that function it means, for example that I couldn't use rollupjs bundler with rxjs correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath, they use the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which actually does not need async/await or promises to implement. For example, when you have a DOM element and add some event listeners to it - you already use the simple observer implementation and it doesn't brake anything.

Also, here is a nice [short article](https://pawelgrzybek.com/the-observer-pattern-in-javascript-explained/) explaining it with an examples in Javascript.

You may use any bundler you want with, rxjs library can not brake it.

*Note*, that you *can* convert an observable to promise if you need with a `toPromise` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html).

Comment: wow good answer. I don't think I'll need to convert an observable to a promise. I'm happy with the behavior I have now.